# EF core error while add migration

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have problem with  EF core error while add migration. Here is my code

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
            builder.Entity<Subject>().HasKey(s => s.Id);
            builder.Entity<Subject>().Property(c => c.Name)
                .HasMaxLength(100)
                .IsRequired();


            // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
            // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
            // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }
    }
```

I want to add migration with nuget but get this error

> Add-Migration "New"
>   C:\Applications\Projects\Education\src\Education.Web.Admin.Frontend.App\project.json(34,43):
>   warning NU1012: Dependency conflict. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
>   1.1.1 expected Microsoft.Extensions.Logging >= 1.1.1 but received 1.0.0 No parameterless constructor was found on 'ApplicationDbContext'. Either add a parameterless constructor to
>   'ApplicationDbContext' or add an implementation of
>   'IDbContextFactory' in the same assembly as
>   'ApplicationDbContext'.

Comment: you should lern to read the exception-message. `No parameterless constructor was found on 'ApplicationDbContext'` says everything. The solution on how to solve is declared too: `Either add a parameterless constructor to 'ApplicationDbContext' or add an implementation of 'IDbContextFactory' in the same assembly as 'ApplicationDbContext'.`

Answer (score 0):

The error message seems clear enough. your Db context class has no parameterless constructor. You should add one like this:

```
public ApplicationDbContext() : base("your connection string") {}
```

Comment: What error are you getting this time? @FatikhanGasimov